# How to Call Rest WCF service using HTTPWebRequest or Webclient?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, httpwebrequest, webclient

Hi i Have created WCF service , Service contract and Data contract is pasted below

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestWithXML
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "Post", UriTemplate = "DoWork", RequestFormat=                WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string DoWork(Test objtest);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "Post", UriTemplate = "Method?test={strtest}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string Method(Test objtest,string strtest);

}          

[DataContract]
public class Test
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

How should i test these services in .NET . I can able to test the methods by changing method "Post" to  "GET" .

But I have to test these services using "Post" . Please guide me

thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you're using WCF and the `WebInvoke` attribute doesn't mean you can search for the more generic terms.

You're just looking for a way to "test POST to REST service", and if you type that into your favourite web search engine, the following hits may turn up:

- [How to consume WCF WebInvoke Method : The Official Microsoft ASP.NET Forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1677895.aspx/1)
- [Testing REST webservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203495/testing-rest-webservices)
- [Is there a REST service test client/app somewhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198435/is-there-a-rest-service-test-client-app-somewhere)
- [What tools do you use to test your public REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486658/what-tools-do-you-use-to-test-your-public-rest-api)
- [Best tool/framework for testing a RESTful service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414875/best-tool-framework-for-testing-a-restful-service)
- [Complete RESTful API debugging/testing tool](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97404/complete-restful-api-debugging-testing-tool).
- [Test Client for testing WCF Rest services or just use browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433812/test-client-for-testing-wcf-rest-services-or-just-use-browser)

These search results will lead you to, among others:

- [rest-client - Java application to test HTTP/RESTful webservices. - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)
- Google Chrome extension: [REST Console Launcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console-launcher/faceofpmfclkengnkgkgjkcibdbhemoc)
- [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)
- [HTTP4e, REST HTTP client plugin for Eclipse. Make a Restful call.](http://www.ywebb.com/)
- https://apigee.com/console/others
- Firefox add-on: [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/)
- [Consuming WCF REST Services Using jQuery AJAX Calls - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128478/Consuming-WCF-REST-Services-Using-jQuery-AJAX-Call)
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- SoapUI: [Getting Started with REST Testing | REST Testing](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html)
- [rest-client - Java application to test HTTP/RESTful webservices. - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)
- [Apache JMeter - Apache JMeter™](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the Method to "POST".
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx

```
var myWebRequest = new HTTPWebRequest();
myWebRequest.Method = "POST"
```

Comment: Thanks Grumbler .. Let me try :)

Answer (score 0):

To test a POST request, you have to change some things in your code :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "DoWork", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string DoWork(Stream objtest);
```

You set the parameter to Stream.

In the implementation of DoWork(Stream objtest) :

```
public string DoWork(Stream objtest)
{
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
     string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
     sr.Dispose();
     NameValueCollection collection = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);
     return collection.ToString();
}
```

To test you request, you have to use a REST Client (Fiddler ?) and the content of you body will be in the collection.

If you want to create the request in C#:

```
string body ="&key1=value1&key2=value2";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(body);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..I have tried but I'm getting Remote Server returned error .Method Not Allowed Error